# What does executeQuery(String sql) return when there are no results?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if resultset has one row or more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591732/how-to-check-if-resultset-has-one-row-or-more)

What will `executeQuery(String sql)` return when the result of the SQL Query is zero rows>? If it returns a `ResultSet` Object, how will we detect that the SQL Query has returned nothing.

Assume the SQL Query to be a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Did you try that? should return or Empty resultSet

Comment: @JigarJoshi how will we detect that the returned object contains zero rows?

Comment: [`resultSet.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) returns `false` in case there is no more data

Comment: The best way I found was in the second part of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867194/java-resultset-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-results) SO answer where he does the check without using `next()`. Btw, yes, it returns a ResultSet object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you check [ResultSet's next method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) . Initially the ResultSet's cursor points to before the first row, the very first call to next() returns false implies there was no data in the ResultSet. See [How do I get the size of a ResultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset) , since there is no direct size() or length() method for Resultsets in Java.

Answer (score 4):

The next() method of the resultSet moves the cursor to the next row and returns a boolean that indicates if a data has been read or not. Usually it's used with a while loop

`while (myresultset.next()){
//some statement;
}`

In your case the fist call of the next method will return false if no data matche the query.

Comment: Is it that myresultset.first() and myresultset.next() does the same work for first call??

Comment: Yes I guess, event if it depends of the implementation. Give it a try.

Comment: Use `if(myresult.next())` If there is nothing then it will return false.

Answer (score 3):

it will return a ResultSet. Use

> boolean hasResult = rs.next();

to find out if there is a result row.

Answer (score 1):

Empty resultSet with zero rows i.e. `resultSet.next()` will return false.

Comment: there is no size() or length() method for Resultsets in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If the `ResultSet` returned is empty, then the output of the first invocation of the `next()` method on this ResultSet will return false.

Basically the usual procedure is something among the lines

```
ResultSet rs = executeQuery("select ....");
while(rs.next()) {
    //do something with the results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return empty `ResultSet` if the query fetches 0 records.
Initially the cursor points to before resultset, when ever we call `resultset.next()` cursor moves to next `resultset` (Iterator patter) and return `true` if there are any results exists, otherwise it just returns `false`. In this case the first call to `next()` method returns `false`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `rs.getRow()` method.

```
 if(rs.getRow() >= 1){
      //Has at least 1 result
    }
```

[Source:](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/sql/ResultSet.java.html)

```
/**
    * Retrieves the current row number.  The first row is number 1, the
    * second number 2, and so on.
    * <p>
    * <strong>Note:</strong>Support for the <code>getRow</code> method
    * is optional for <code>ResultSet</code>s with a result
    * set type of <code>TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY</code>
    *
    * @return the current row number; <code>0</code> if there is no current row
    * @exception SQLException if a database access error occurs
    * or this method is called on a closed result set
    * @exception SQLFeatureNotSupportedException if the JDBC driver does not support
    * this method
    * @since 1.2
 */
      int getRow() throws SQLException;
```