# Can a ResultSet be 'null' in Java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, null, resultset

I have a very basic bit of code which executes a select query and returns a boolean depending if the result set is empty or not.

```
public boolean checkIfUserHasPreferences(String username){
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean checkBoolean = false;

        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(Messages.getString("OracleUserManagement.0"), Messages.getString("OracleUserManagement.1"), Messages.getString("OracleUserManagement.2")); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$

            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT USERNAME FROM USER_PREFERENCES WHERE USERNAME = ?"); 
            statement.setString(1, username);
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (rs == null){
                System.out.println("I checked it was true!");
                checkBoolean = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("I checked it was false!");
                checkBoolean = false;
            }

            con.commit();

            con.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return checkBoolean;
    }
```

What confuses is me that even though the table/database is empty, it always prints out "I checked it was false!".

Is this because even if a result set returns 0 rows, it does not = null? Should I be using while (rs.next()) to check instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could have looked onto the API of [`Statement#executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) method. It says:

> **Returns:**
>
> - a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the given query; **never null**

Emphasis mine.

> Should I be using while (rs.next()) to check instead?

Yes.

Comment: @oOTesterOo. Of course. You should first visit the API, when in problem. That's what they are there for.

Answer (score 6):

No, ResultSet returned by executeQuery(java.lang.String) method can **never be null**.

Moreover, the standard way to check whether a ResultSet is empty or not is to try setting its cursor to first row by using its `first()` and if it returns false it indicates that ResultSet is empty.

So, in your case you don't even need to check rather just `return rs.first();`

For example:

```
if (!rs.first()) {
    // handle empty set: throw error or return
}

// continue processing the ResultSet further
do {
    // ...
} while (rs.next());
```

Comment: It is too many steps, just checking rs.next() and then process the cursor instead

Comment: @kidnan1991 the solution lets you handle scenario where you want to take some action on empty resultset

Answer (score 2):

The result set will not be null until and unless:

> 1.It is initialized to null and done nothing else,
>
> 2.If the statement on which execute query is written is not correct(sql exception will occur and initialization will not happen).

This is irrelevant for this question, but will serve as a tip for people like me.

This happen when database operation is done in a separate class where statement.executeQuery() is given in try-catch which has no e.printStackTrace() or any other logging mechanics.

I have confronted with this error and that is the reason why I am writing.  This can be a great problem when we do a batch process  where one out of 50000 execution causes an exception(in my case:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -805,
>   SQLSTATE: 51002

this error was caused around 20000 iteration ) which causes unwanted result.