# java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set. dor select statement

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jsp, servlets

I am trying to fetch the values from testcase table but its throwing  java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set and 
Here is my code,

```
try {
            tcID=con.prepareStatement("select tc_id,tc_name from testcase where project_id=?  and tc_id=? ");
            tcID.setString(1,project);
            tcID.setString(2,tciD);
            ResultSet rs = tcID.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("Loop TC ID....."+rs.getString("tc_id"));
            System.out.println("Loop TC Name......"+rs.getString("tc_name"));
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("Inside While.....");
                ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into execution_testcases (project_id, Rel_id, testcase_id, testcase_name, Flag) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
                ps.setString(1, project);
                ps.setString(2, RelName);
                ps.setString(3, rs.getString("tc_id"));
                ps.setString(4, rs.getString("tc_name"));
                ps.setString(5, "true");
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
            String cmd= "java -jar D:\\FrameworkCodeDev\\Backups\\WebDriverJarFiles\\Build Release\\Framework_TAF_V10.jar";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (SQLException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should remove System.out.println("Loop TC ID....."+rs.getString("tc_id"));
            System.out.println("Loop TC Name......"+rs.getString("tc_name")); before while (rs.next())

Comment: that i removed and working on it

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to get strings out of `ResultSet` if there's no data. You need to check if there's data before calling `rs.getString()`, you can use `isBeforeFirst()` to do this.

```
    ResultSet rs = tcID.executeQuery();
    if(rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
        System.out.println("Loop TC ID....."+rs.getString("tc_id"));
        System.out.println("Loop TC Name......"+rs.getString("tc_name"));
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("Inside While.....");
            ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into execution_testcases (project_id, Rel_id, testcase_id, testcase_name, Flag) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, project);
            ps.setString(2, RelName);
            ps.setString(3, rs.getString("tc_id"));
            ps.setString(4, rs.getString("tc_name"));
            ps.setString(5, "true");
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No data in RS!");
    }
```

Original answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6813771/1627055

Comment: in rs.isBeforeFirst() is coming as false for me

Comment: You run that query against your server manually and see if it provides any results.

Comment: I have set the values like this tcID.setInt(1,1);
    tcID.setInt(2,250);
now the query executing and returning the values but wgy its not working for setString()????

Comment: IIRC not all SQL server implementations do typecasts string<->int on the fly, so if your `project_id` is `int` then you should use `setInt()`, both to avoid extraneous type conversion and avoid comparing `250` to `"250"` with an obvious result of false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your System.out.println statements as you trying to print the elements of an empty resultset. You should try by removing them:

```
try {
    tcID=con.prepareStatement("select tc_id,tc_name from testcase where project_id=?  and tc_id=? ");
    tcID.setInt(1,project);
    tcID.setInt(2,tciD);
    ResultSet rs = tcID.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println("Inside While.....");
        ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into execution_testcases (project_id, Rel_id, testcase_id, testcase_name, Flag) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, project);
        ps.setString(2, RelName);
        ps.setString(3, rs.getString("tc_id"));
        ps.setString(4, rs.getString("tc_name"));
        ps.setString(5, "true");
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    String cmd= "java -jar D:\\FrameworkCodeDev\\Backups\\WebDriverJarFiles\\Build Release\\Framework_TAF_V10.jar";
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
} catch (SQLException e) {          
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi Guneli, I have removed sout and run the same but its not entering into the while loop, but everything corect only am getting exact parameter from the jquery and having values in bd

Comment: Hi. Are you sure that your query is returning data?

Comment: select tc_id,tc_name from testcase where project_id=1  and tc_id=250;
the id 1 and 250 is coming from UI the above query i have executed in the sql work benchand its returning the data.

Comment: Not sure if it will make sense, but can you, please, try tcID.setInt(1,project);
tcID.setInt(2,tciD); instead of setString.

Comment: @Suganth, did you try this?