# Check if ResultSet is empty in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB in my program. I want to check if my Result Set is empty or not.

```
//check if empty first
if(results.next() == false){
System.out.println("empty");
}

//display results
while (results.next()) {
String data = results.getString("first_name");
//name.setText(data);
System.out.println(data);
}
```

The above method is not working properly. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867194/java-resultset-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-results) I have to call `.first()` or `.beforeFirst()` to rest the cursor to the first row, but `.first()` and `.beforFirst()` are not supported in HSQL. I also tried to add `connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);`
but I still get the same outcome (I get the message empty and the data from the DB!!!)
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the problem?
An observation: the `results.next()` moves the cursor to the first row when called for the first time (in the `if`). Hence, if there is data, your while loop's condition will move it to the second row when it starts effectively skipping the first row. You may use a do-while loop instead.

Comment: The question you linked to also has answer for `FORWARD_ONLY` resultsets (eg: the accepted answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand your objective, you could use `do while` loop

```
if (!results.next()) {
  System.out.println("empty");
} else {
  //display results
  do {
    String data = results.getString("first_name");
    //name.setText(data);
    System.out.println(data);
  } while (results.next());
}
```

Or, you could just keep a `count` like so,

```
int count = 0;
//display results
while (results.next()) {
  String data = results.getString("first_name");
  //name.setText(data);
  System.out.println(data);
  count++;
}
if (count < 1) {
  // Didn't even read one row
}
```