# How to compare user input with my database in java

Tags: java, jdbc

As shown on the title, I have tried so hard to compare the user input with my database and it works with a true input. However, when the input is not exist on my database I don't know what is wrong in my below code, please help.

```
private class da implements ActionListener{
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           Connection con = null;

      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/المكتبة";
      String unicode = "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
  try{
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+unicode,"root","");

 PreparedStatement upd = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM library WHERE author =?'");
 upd.setString(1,name.getText());
 ResultSet rs = upd.executeQuery();


while(rs.next()){
    String authorname = rs.getString("author");
    String bookname = rs.getString("bookname");
    String categort = rs.getString("category");
    int isbn = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ISBN"));
    String data = "اسم المؤلف: "+authorname+"\n"+"اسم الكتاب: "+bookname+"\n"+"التصنيف: "+categort+"\n"+"ISBN: "+isbn;


 if(name.getText().equals(authorname))
     txt.setText(data);
 else
     txt.setText("no matches");
```

Comment: it works when the inputs are equal, but can't when input is not match

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to this section:

```
while(rs.next()){

 // ... other code 

 if(name.getText().equals(authorname))
     txt.setText(data);
 else
     txt.setText("no matches");
```

If the value of `name.getText()` is not found in your database, `rs.next()` will never return true. Since you've enclosed your `if` block **inside of the while loop**, it will never be executed if no match is found in your database. You could solve it a number of ways, one way is to do something like this instead:

```
boolean has_results = rs.next();

if(has_results){

    do {
        // ... your loop code
    }while(rs.next());

}else {
    text.setText("No Matches");
}
```

In this code, if the first call to `rs.next()` returns `false`, we know nothing we returned from the database. Otherwise, loop as normal. In this instance, I changed the loop to a post-checking `do...while` loop instead, since we want to check `rs.next()` at the end of the loop now.

**Note:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6813771/877472) demonstrates another way of checking whether the result set contains rows.

Comment: Thank you, it works. but I can't do it for the other fields, do you know how to do it?

Comment: do what, exactly, for the other fields?

Comment: this work for only one field("name" I mean) when i try to make the same function to the other fields it doesn't execute. However, when I connect 2 listeners to one button it doesn't work, but it work for single listener for each button

Comment: @Forenkazan I don't think there is enough information to answer that. The question is, if this one listener method is used for all of the fields, how would you determine which field you are supposed to be using at any given time. That's what you'll need to figure out, but unfortunately that's beyond the scope of this question. After you've figured out a little more, it may be easier to post a new question asking about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should close the while() loop before the if/else.

It is not the prettiest of code though.

Comment: it's just a sample of my code, the error is not with the compiler