# using ResultSet when row value from database is NULL

Tags: java, netbeans

When querying the database directly, result is `NULL`, now Im using `ResultSet` to check if *result is NULL*, do something else, if result is not NULL, print the result: This my COde:

```
if(rs4 != null) {
            while(rs4.next()) {
            String ad =rs4.getString("number");                    
            System.out.println(ad);
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("ZERO ENTRIES");
        }`
```

Database row value is NULL,since there is no row returned from my query so definitely i expect the else statement to run, but now the if statement is still being excecuted and prints `null`

Comment: Even if there are no results, rs4 should still not be null (unless your code does something strange).

Comment: Assuming you are using `Statement`and `executeQuery` , it returns : "a `ResultSet` object that contains the data produced by the given query; _never null_"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ResultSet how to check if there are any results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867194/java-resultset-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-results)

Comment: @steveSmith oh, okay, coz it prints true, so I need to check the value from the number collumn that is returned, it is supposed to be some numbers, but since i have no data for the selected query, it is empty. How do I go around that and print something different....

Comment: @berger Im using `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @Beroo : `PreparedStatement` extends `Statement` .

Answer (score 1):

What you see as NULL when querying the DB directly is the value of the column `number`, not the value of the row.

so, that's why you get a `non-null` row with a `NULL` value in `number` column in your `ResultSet`.

Comment: oh, so how can I restructure my code to cater for that outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
    System.out.println("No data"); 
}
```

Or:

```
if (!resultSet.next() ) {
    System.out.println("no data");
}
```

Comment: as states by @alayor above, the row value returned is `NULL`, meaning there is something being returned, and I need a way to get past that. Row value is expected to be numbers, digits, and when empty, it should be `null` as expected, ....I want to get around that `null` aspect and print something else

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull() this maybe helps...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to go around it.  Using `rs.getInt()` this will return `0` whenever row value is `NULL` and return new row value , whenever there is a row found.

This solved it :-)

```
while(rs.next())
        {
            // using rs.getInt() will return zero when row value from your query is NULL
            int i = rs.getInt("number");
            if(i<0) //check if zero
            {
                // When result is NULL i =0
                System.out.println("your value");
            }else{
                //When there are rows found from database i > 0
                String ad=rs.getString("number");
                System.out.println(ad);
            }
        }`
```