# Avoiding skipping a row By next() Method of ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, resultset

This is a simple code print some rows from a Database. but When I execute this nothing is print on screen. I figured that the problem is `rs.next()` method is skipping a row. So How can I avoid that or Reset the Position of `rs.next()` method?

```
 String searchword = Searchtf.getText();
 try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, db_username, db_password);

        java.sql.Statement stat = con.createStatement();

        String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Name LIKE '" + searchword + "' ";

java.sql.ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(searchQuery);

        if (rs.next()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getString("idUser") + " ,");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("Name") + " ,");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("Email") + " ,");
                System.out.println(rs.getString("country") + " .");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
        }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ResultSet how to check if there are any results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867194/java-resultset-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-results)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, stop building SQL like that - use parameterized SQL and a `PreparedStatement`. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Basically, don't call `rs.next()` twice in a row (first in the `if` then in the `while`)... you can easily do that by converting your `while` loop into a `do/while` loop:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    do {
        System.out.print(rs.getString("idUser") + " ,");
        System.out.print(rs.getString("Name") + " ,");
        System.out.print(rs.getString("Email") + " ,");
        System.out.println(rs.getString("country") + " .");
    } while (rs.next());
}
```

Or *just* have the `while` loop, with a separate variable to detect that you've seen *some* results:

```
bool anyResults = false;
while (rs.next()) {
    anyResults = true;
    System.out.print(rs.getString("idUser") + " ,");
    System.out.print(rs.getString("Name") + " ,");
    System.out.print(rs.getString("Email") + " ,");
    System.out.println(rs.getString("country") + " .");
}
if (!anyResults) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
}
```

(Additionally, you should use try-with-resources to close your `ResultSet` etc, and just printing a stack trace to stdout is almost never the appropriate way to handle exceptions...)

Comment: Thank You For Your Answer.. Well I Will Use parameterized SQL and a PreparedStatement in my Future codes.  `rs.relative(-1)` is also worked for me ! I checked it

Comment: @Nazeer: No, fix your *current* code. You have a security vulnerability. Saying "I'll do it right next time" isn't good enough for that. It's really, really, *really* important to get into the habit of protecting yourself from SQL injection, and there's no time better to get started than right now.

Comment: Well Thanks .. I don't have a very good knowledge in parameterized SQL and a PreparedStatement. I'm going to learn it now.

Comment: @Nazeer: Excellent - that's exactly the attitude to take :)

Answer (score 1):

No no need to use :

```
 if (rs.next()) {
```

The while is enough, this make the result two times.
instead you can use :

```
boolean b = false;
while (rs.next()) {
   b = true;
   ...
}

if(!b) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Found");
}
```

---

You have to use PreparedStatement instead, to avoid any SQL Injection or syntax error.

Comment: Without the `if` statement, how would you handle the `else`? There are options there (as per my answer), but you don't recognize it as something to be dealt with in your answer.

Comment: the OP can use a boolean to inside the while to know if there results or not @JonSkeet

Comment: Right, so indicate that in the answer. My point is that they can't *just* remove the `if` statement, as your answer implies.

Answer (score 1):

[The API docs for ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) explain about the next() method:

> Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. A
>   ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

Every time you call the next() method you are moving the cursor to the next row.
This happens in your code (two times) here:

```
if (rs.next()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
```

One way to avoid the problem is to use the method beforeFirst(). 
[According to the API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst()):

> Moves the cursor to the front of this ResultSet object, just before
>   the first row. This method has no effect if the result set contains no
>   rows.

Then, every time you use somewhere in your code "rs.next()" you are moving the cursor one position (to the next row) but if after using rs.next() many times you need to start reading from the first row you can simply use rs.beforeFirst() and when you call the next time rs.next() the cursor will start from the beginning of your result set.

Also you do not need to use the if statement in your code:

```
if (rs.next()) {
```

because the while you use is enough.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.next()` will increment cursor in `if` so if resultset has only one row returned by query then `while` will move cursor again and no data will get print.Use `do..while` loop instead.

```
if (rs.next()) {
            do {
                System.out.print(rs.getString("idUser") + " ,");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("Name") + " ,");
                System.out.print(rs.getString("Email") + " ,");
                System.out.println(rs.getString("country") + " .");
            }while (rs.next());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for every answers. I found that putting `rs.relative(-1)` also does the job. But above answers are well coded and better than mine. So thanks all. I'm a newbie to programming I will consider all your advice in my coding. Thanks

```
if (rs.next()) {
     rs.relative(-1);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString("idUser") + " ,");
            System.out.print(rs.getString("Name") + " ,");
            System.out.print(rs.getString("Email") + " ,");
            System.out.println(rs.getString("country") + " .");
        }
 }
```

Comment: `relative(-1)` will not always work, for example it won't work with a `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` result set, which is usually the default.

Answer (score -2):

Hey it is skipping row because u r doing rs.next() in the if clause and then again in while. So the first iteration which while is doing is actually the second row. Best option will be in if clause u should write if(rs.first())

Comment: That would fail for a forward-only `ResultSet`, and if it succeeds it would *still* skip the first row as the call to `first()` would be followed by a call to `next()`. It's simpler just to make sure that `next` is only called the right number of times - see my answer for two options.