# Executing query with condition in java (response = Illegal operation on empty result set)

Tags: java

I have a problem, I want to execute query based on the condition. The concept is if the result is null, then execute another query. But when I try it, the result is an error

> Illegal operation on empty result set`

My code:

```
String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid=? AND password=? LIMIT 1;";

PreparedStatement pst=null;
pst = con.prepareStatement(strSQL);
pst.setString(1, userid);
pst.setString(2, password);

rs = pst.executeQuery();

if(rs.getString(1) == null && rs.getString(2) == null) {
   String strSQL = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE userid=?;";
}

if(rs.next())
{   
    yoyo yo = new yoyo(); 
    yo.SetUserid(rs.getString(1));
    yo.SetUsername(rs.getString(2));
    yo.SetPosisi(rs.getString(5));
    lstLogin = yo;
}
```

Comment: If no result is found, the query will not return a resultset containing one row with null values. It will return an empty resultset.

Comment: what should i do then

Comment: `if (!rs.next()) { /* new query */ }`

Comment: thanks for helping

Comment: A `ResultSet` is pointing basicly to the index -1 at first, you need to check if there is a `ResultSet.next()` first to be on the first cell (index 0).

Answer (score 1):

At this line you will get the result set

```
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Now we want know that the `rs` is not `null` and also not empty. So we will give condition like this

```
if (rs != null && !rs.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
    String strSQL = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE userid=?;"; 
}
```

> Check this link for reference [Check result set is empty or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867194/java-resultset-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-results/6813771#6813771)

In your code it is not checking whether the `ResultSet` is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have not executed the query when `if(rs.getString(1) == null && rs.getString(2) == null)` condition is true.
To solve this, change the `if` condition as following:

```
if(!rs.next()){
    strSQL = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE userid=?;";
    pst = con.prepareStatement(strSQL);
    pst.setString(1, userid);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
}
```

**Note:** You have re-declared `strSQL` variable in `if` statement.