# How to check object result is more then 0 in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following code to get and return records count from the database and assign it into the object.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST" );
```

I have the following code to check whether records is found:

```
    if (rs.next() && rs.getString( 1 ).equals( "1" )) {
        logger.info( "DID Find Records !!! " );
    } else {
        logger.info( "DID NOT Find Records !!! " );
    }
```

How can I check return records is more then 0 in this case?

Comment: why don't you do `if (rs.next() && rs.getInt(1) > 0 ))` instead of `if (rs.next() && rs.getString( 1 ).equals( "1" ))`? or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: looks like just `if (rs.next())` is fine. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867194/java-resultset-how-to-check-if-there-are-any-results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`if (rs.next() && rs.getString( 1 ).equals( "1" ))`

by

`if (rs.next() && rs.getInt(1) > 0))`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an alias, then extract the returned `count` from `rs` as an integer, simply change your code to this:

```
  rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST AS TESTCOUNT" );
  rs.next();
  if (rs.getInt("TESTCOUNT") > 0) {
    logger.info( "DID Find Records !!! " );
  } else {
    logger.info( "DID NOT Find Records !!! " );
  }
```

where `'TESTCOUNT'` is the alias name given.

Comment: Your code is missing `rs.next()`. Result sets are initially positioned **before** the first row, not on the first row.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.getString( 1 )` contains value of row count from database. Just parse it to Integer to the number of rows

```
 if (rs!=null && rs.next()) {
        logger.info( "DID Find Records !!! " );
        logger.info( "RowCount "+ Integer.valueOf(rs.getString( 1 )));
    } else {
        logger.info( "DID NOT Find Records !!! " );
    }
```

Comment: There is not need to use `Integer.valueOf(rs.getString( 1 ))`, using `rs.getInt(1)`  works well enough. And `executeQuery` should **never** return `null`, so that null-check is unnecessary.

Comment: Then an exception would be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Make it to a int variable and do the checks...!

```
ResultSet rs = .....;

int count = -1;

if (rs.next())
    count = rs.getInt(1);

if (count <= 0)
{
    logger.info("no records");
}
else if (count == 1)
{
    logger.info("found 1 record");
}
else
{
    logger.info("found more...");
}bb
```