# How to loop sql statement in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a for cycle with a dynamic sql statement:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {         
            ps2 = db.prepareStatement("select * from student where id=?");
            ps2.setInt(1,studList[i]);
            rs2=ps2.executeQuery();
            while(rs2.next()){
                list1.add(new Student(rs2.getInt("id"), rs2.getString("name"), rs2.getString("city"));
            }
            rs2.close();
            ps2.close();
        }
```

studList[i] is an array with all the student ID and the variable "size" is the length of this array. The problem with this code is that only one element is added to the list(corresponding to the first student ID). 
I noticed that the code goes inside 'while(rs2.next())' just if the value of studList[i] doesn't change. Why?

Comment: put `rs2.close();
            ps2.close();` outside of for-loop and check.

Comment: @dkb same result

Comment: change `while(rs2.next()){` with `while(rs2.hasNext()){`, and at the end of while loop `rs2 = rs2.next();`, this is what I Mean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/867206/2987755

Comment: @dkb hasNext() return 'cannot find symbol' error

Comment: Try this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6813771/2987755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemingly the logic is fine.

First the code would be better with

- local declarations at the first usage, otherwise ps2, rs2, ps3, rs3 and so one risk undetected typos;
- *try-with-resources* that close even on exception/return.

So:

```
String sql = "select name, city from student where id=?";
try (PreparedStatement ps2 = db.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {  
        int id = studList[i];
        ps2.setInt(1, id);
        try (ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery()) {
            System.out.printf("[%d] %d%n", i, id);
            while (rs2.next()) {
                System.out.printf("- %s%n", rs2.getString("name"));
                list1.add(new Student(id, rs2.getString("name"), rs2.getString("city"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the error might happen before: the array filled false, the database student table corrupted.

One beginner error is to reuse an object (Student), with new field values. Adding the same object to a list then would have the last student's data replicated several times.

Here it could be that in the original code code was called reusing ps2 or such.

Comment: same error, just one time inside 'while (rs2.next())'

Comment: One time in the `while` is okay (could have been `if`), as `id` is the primary key.

Comment: but is not the result that i'm expecting, the list should have 2 entries but it has just 1

Comment: And the second id is in the database?

Comment: (And `new Student` does not do beginner's error like `static` fields.) The printfs indeed show [0]... / - ... / [1] ... / nothing. Then it _must_ be the database or the code shown is not the code used. You principly had correct code.

Comment: **The second id should not be present in the database table.**

Comment: there was an error before in the code, now it works. Thank you!!